# Spring Batch Taking more than 1 hour to process 20--30k records

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, h2

The spring batch taking more than hour to process 20 to 30k record. i am using ItemStremReader, ItemProcessor and JpaItemWriter with partitioned and have a grid size is 6 and each chunk size is 500 and batch-size =1000,Here i am using H2 as a database.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnAderBatchStep(BATCH_NAME)
@Import({AsynchronousTasksConfiguration.class, BankAccountsReaderWriterConfiguration.class})
@Slf4j
public class ParallelClientBankAccountImportStepConfiguration {

    public static final String STEP_NAME = "parallelClientBankAccountsImportStep";
    public static final String ITEM_WRITER_NAME = "bankAccountsItemWriter";
    public static final String ITEM_READER_NAME = "bankAccountsItemReader";

   
 
    @Bean
    public Step parallelClientBankAccountsImportStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                                                      PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager,
                                                      @Value("${batch.export.parallel.grid-size:6}") int gridSize,
                                                      ItemWriter<BankAccount> itemWriter,
                                                      TaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor,
                                                      ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        log.info("Configuring the [{}].", STEP_NAME);
        String slaveStepName = "slaveBankAccountsImportStep";
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_NAME)
                .partitioner(slaveStepName, partitioner())
                .gridSize(gridSize)
                .step(slaveStep(slaveStepName, stepBuilderFactory, itemWriter, jpaTransactionManager, applicationEventPublisher))
                .taskExecutor(applicationEventPublisher)
                .transactionManager(jpaTransactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    protected final Partitioner partitioner() {
        return gridSize -> {
            Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>(gridSize);
            for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
                ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
                context.put("index", i);
                map.put("partition_" + i, context);
            }
            return map;
        };
    }

    protected Step slaveStep(String slaveStepName,
                             StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                             ItemWriter<BankAccount> itemWriter,
                             PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager, ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(slaveStepName)
                .transactionManager(jpaTransactionManager)
                .<ClientBankAccount, BankAccount> chunk(500)
                .reader(itemReader(null, 0, 0))
                .processor(itemProcessor(null))
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .listener(chunkLogger())
                .listener(stepLogger(applicationEventPublisher))
                .build();
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public ItemStreamReader<ClientBankAccount> itemReader(ClientBankAccountsItemReader itemReader,
                                       @Value("${batch.export.parallel.grid-size:6}")
                                       int gridSize,
                                       @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[index]}")
                                       int partitionIndex) {
        
        ItemStreamReader<ClientBankAccount> itemStreamReader  = new ClientParallelItemStreamReader(itemReader, gridSize, partitionIndex);

       
        return itemStreamReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<ClientBankAccount, BankAccount> itemProcessor(ClientBankAccountMapper mapper) {
        
        ItemProcessor<ClientBankAccount, BankAccount> itemProcessor =  mapper::fromClientService;
        long elapsedTime = startTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        return itemProcessor;
    }
}


ItemReader class:

@Slf4j
@Service
public class ClientBankAccountsItemReader extends AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader<ClientBankAccount> {

    private final ReactiveClientService clientService;
    private Disposable clientBankAccounts;

    private BlockingQueue<ClientBankAccount> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private boolean isOpen = false;

  

    public ClientBankAccountsItemReader(ReactiveClientService clientService) {
        this.clientService = clientService;
        setName("ClientBankAccountsItemReader");
    }

    public synchronized boolean isOpen() {
        return this.isOpen;
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void doOpen()throws Exception {
        if (!isOpen) {
            log.info("Opening the Client Account Reader...");
            // subscribing to a flux does the actual call to Client
            clientBankAccounts = clientService.getAccountsApi(getSearchAccountRequest()).subscribe(this::addToQueue);
          
            this.isOpen = true;
          
           
        }
    }

    private void addToQueue(ClientBankAccount ba) {
        try {
            if (!queue.offer(ba, 5, MILLISECONDS)) {
                log.warn("Could not add Client Bank Account to the internal queue!");
                log.trace("Client Bank Account:\n\t{}", ba);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.warn("INTERRUPTED! Could not ADD Client Bank Account to the internal queue!");
        }
       
    }

    @Override
    protected void doClose() {
        if (this.clientBankAccounts != null) {
            this.clientBankAccounts.dispose();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientBankAccount doRead() {
        try {
         
            return this.queue.poll(50, SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.warn("INTERRUPTED! Could not READ client Bank Account from the internal queue!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private SearchAccountRequest getSearchAccountRequest(){
        SearchAccountRequest searchAccountRequest= new SearchAccountRequest();
       //request details are set
        return searchAccountRequest;

    }
}

ItemWriter class:

@Slf4j
public class BankAccountJpaItemWriter extends JpaItemWriter<BankAccount> {

    private final JpaItemWriter<CABankAccount> closedAccountsWriter;
   //declared few repository...

    public BankAccountJpaItemWriter(Parms...) {
       //parameterised constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends BankAccount> items) {
    
        
        if (isEmpty(items)) {
            return;
        }

        List<BankAccount> activeBankAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
        List<CABankAccount> closedBankAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BankAccount account : items) {
           //business logic calling repository to few detail
        }
       
        super.write(activeBankAccounts);
        
        closedAccountsWriter.write(closedBankAccounts);
        
    }
}
```

Since it is big impact on performance and I need to optimize the process?

Comment: The first step is measuring. What part of your code is taking up most of the time? Once you find that out, you can look for where in that piece of code you can do things more efficiently.

Comment: itemWriter process taking lot of time. to write the record in the DB

Comment: You also have business logic in the itemWriter; are you sure there is nothing slow there?